# How to export Outlook email body to a Unicode text file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, unicode, export

My emails in Outlook 2010 have Unicode characters inside their body, so when I want to export them to a .txt file (Tab Separated In Windows) I got many question marks in output file!

How can I fix this problem? Is there any option in Outlook to change that file's format?

Comment: When you say "export them to a txt file" are you talking about using the `save as` feature? Is the program you are opening the text file with able to understand Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook when you save as text it will, by default, use the default system [codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page). It's a bit unclear but you can change this behavior.

After you click on `Save As` and choose a filename you get this warning:

[image: warning]

You have to click on `No` to get an option to change the format. When you do you get this dialog:

[image: format]

Select the `Other encoding:` radio button and select `Unicode` in the list. This will give you a text file encoded as Unicode without the question marks or boxes.