# How to export Outlook 2016 email body to a Unicode text file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My emails in Outlook 2016 have Unicode characters inside their body, so when I want to export them to a .txt file (Tab Separated In Windows) I got many question marks in output file!

I have to mention that, after I click on **Save As** and choose a **filename** I get no warning dialog box, which could allow me to choose **Unicode** encoding.

Moreover, I have already selected, at **International options**, Unicode (UTF-8), as preferred encoding for **outgoing messages**, and the same for **vCards**.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, double click to open the email you received and manually choose the proper Encoding again, then Select File > Save as > Save as type: Text only > Save, and you will the warning dialog box.

Then you could follow the steps mentioned in this similar thread:[How to export Outlook email body to a Unicode text file?](https://superuser.com/questions/582937/how-to-export-outlook-email-body-to-a-unicode-text-file) to see if your issue could be resolved.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this works if you want to export a single email. However, if you want to export emails in bulk, none of this is working anymore. Is there a solution for email bulk export?

Comment: Seems could not found a workaround for emails in bulk yet.